# How can click on item in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, onclicklistener

How i can click on item In ViewPager. I want to return position current item,that i click. For example, i try to run next code:

```
pager.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            pager.getCurrentItem(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        }
    });
```

But nothing happend. I have allready written options onClick in layout for ViewPager. Maybe anybody can tell me, what i do wrong ?

Comment: Please post full code of your class!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why dont you add your onclick listener to the fragment. then just broadcast an intent.

```
public class Your extends  Fragment
{
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle  savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlayout, null);
    inflatedView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent temp =  new Intent("anything.com.com.CHECK_CURRENT_PAGE_ITEM");
    getActivity().sendBroadcast(temp);
    }
    });
    }
}
```

Then in your Main activity register  a broadcast receiver

```
public class Youractivity extends FragmentActivity
{

private BroadcastReceiver clickedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        pager.getCurrentItem(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
...
   registerBroadcstReceiver(clickedReceiver, new IntentFilter("anything.com.com.CHECK_CURRENT_PAGE_ITEM"))

...
}
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
unregisterBroadcastReceiver()
}
}
```